# Order in web services

Tags: java, web-services

I i am sending some data using web services for example

record 1
record 2
record 3

and i will get some 3 key values one for each record back is there a guarantee that the order is maintained

i.e the first key is for record 1
the second key is for record 2
and the third one is for the record 3

Please let me know.

Kaddy

Comment: Is it 3 different calls to the WS to send the 3 records? or is it in one call where you send a collection of records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the web service call has reached the server it *is* possible to synchronize them so that it guarantee's the ordering. But whenever data is being passed over the network there is no guarantee that record 1 will reach the web service before record 2.